# Editor.js Header and other tools do not work on

Tags: angular, editorjs

I am trying to use ***Editor.js*** in one of my Angular apps and when I try to configure heading, lists and other blocks, it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of undefined
    at e.value (bundle.js:10)
    at new e (bundle.js:10)
    at e.value (editor.js:2)
    at e.value (editor.js:2)
    at e.value (editor.js:2)
    at e.value (editor.js:2)
    at e.value (editor.js:2)
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (editor.js:2)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
```

This is the code snippet of my component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';
import Header from '@editorjs/header';
import List from '@editorjs/list';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editorjs',
  templateUrl: './editorjs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editorjs.component.css']
})
export class EditorjsComponent implements OnInit {

  editor;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.editor = new EditorJS({
      holder: 'editor-js',
      tools: {
        header: {
          class: Header,
          shortcut: 'CMD+SHIFT+H',
        },
        list: {
          class: List,
          inlineToolbar: true,
        },
      }
    });
  }

  onSave() {
    this.editor.save().then((outputData) => {
      console.log('Article data: ', outputData)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Saving failed: ', error)
    });
  }
}
```

The paragraph tool works fine, I get the error only when I try to configure the rest of the tools.

Comment: Stackblitz code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ypbuje

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error, can you paste the lnik with error? also did you checkout this package ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kolkov/angular-editor  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-editor-wysiwyg-patbbf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please refer to this screen recording: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D4D8NA2fzwI6bu-9jc416TxdaTDluwyY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, I did see that package, however I liked editor.js as of it's look & feel and it saves data in JSON format which makes the goal that I am trying to achieve way easier comparing to the other editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just **remove** and **reinstall editorjs** packages, it should fix the problem.

I had a similar problem with [react-editor-js](https://github.com/Jungwoo-An/react-editor-js). It was resolved when I reinstalled it.
The error was probably a result of mismatched versions of editorjs and its tool packages.